# How to solve rate of return in python

Tags: python

Does anyone know if there is a function in python that can solve for rate of return based on variable payments.   for instance
cash flows = 5000 , 10000, 0, 0, 6000 with an ending fund value of 50,000
solve for r such that

5000 * ( 1+r)^5 + 10000 * (1+r)^4 + 0* (1+r)^3 +0*(1+r)^2 +6000*(1+r)1 = 50000

r should solve for 34%

have looked into numpy.rate but it does not account for variable payment but rather a flat fixed payment for 5 years.

Comment: You can use ```sympy.solve```

Comment: thanks Sujay ....i appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the internal rate of return, (`r`) and then check to see if it gives the correct ending value of 50000.

See [numpy_financial](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial/)

(I got 0.2689942559381253 as the rate).

```
>>> from numpy_financial import irr
>>> r = irr([-5000,-10000,0,0,-6000, 50000])
>>> 5000*(1+r)**5 + 10000*(1+r)**4 + 6000*(1+r)
49999.99999999977
>>> r
0.2689942559381253
```

Comment: Thanks Chris Charley ...this answered my question.  We should be looking at IRR functions.....greatly appreciated.